# How to convet this data to array?(Typescript )

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have data coming from api where one of the attribute has value like,

```
[{
......
attr_name: "["abcd"]"
attr_names:"{abcd}"
.......
}]
```

How do i convert this value to array  ["abcd"] ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information. What value do you want to convert? `attr_name` or `attr_names` ?

Comment: I want to covert the value in attr_name to array

Comment: Are you getting data in this format from api `attr_names:{"abcd"}` or in some key value pair ? Value of `attr_names` should be in object format.

Comment: Value of attr_names is in string format..and I'm the data exactly like given above

Comment: Does the data returned is created by you? Because for `"["abcd"]"` ,the compiler will read  `"["` as a string and the abcd as a variable which will cause  `Error: Unexpected identifier`.

Comment: No the data is not create by me...this is coming from api...or can you help me to convert attr_names to array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `JSON.parse` which will convert `json string` to `object`.
Loop over `data` array and convert it and assign back it itself as below.

```
data.forEach(d => d.attr_name = JSON.parse(d.attr_name));
```

```js
let data = [{
  attr_name: '["abcd"]',
  attr_names: "{abcd}"
}];

data.forEach(d => d.attr_name = JSON.parse(d.attr_name));
console.log(data);
```